# Turning off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is it a good idea?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to get customers that are in 'order' table but not in 'customer' table. "Quick order" customers. And I wrote that query:

```
SELECT `email`, `firstname` , `lastname`, `telephone`, `ip`, NULL
FROM `order`
WHERE `customer_id` = 0 AND `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `ocustomer`)
GROUP BY `email`
```

But I'm getting:

> SELECT list contains nonaggregated column (firstname, lastname, telephone, ip) this is incompatible
>   with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I have two options here:

1. Turning OFF ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. I know how to do that but is it a good idea? I know that this is useful but in my case if it is turned ON I need to rewrite my query
2. Using ANY_VALUE(), but it does not work with MariaDb. In other hand I cannot use aggregate functions because I have text fields. So I have no idea what else to change here to work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

I'm confused what to do? Is it good idea to turn off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY or may be there is another way to rewrite my query without ANY_VALUE()?

Comment: If you talk about `any_value()` I guess you talk about enclosing each column, that is not `email` with `any_value()`? If so you don't seem to care to get column values from one row but are OK with them being from different rows. Then you can just use `min()` or `max()` on that columns as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to turn it off. It helps you to avoid mistakes, that would lead to wrong query results.

You can write your query like this:

```
SELECT `email`, `firstname` , `lastname`, `telephone`, `ip`, NULL
FROM `order`
WHERE `customer_id` = 0 AND `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `ocustomer`)
GROUP BY `email`, `firstname` , `lastname`, `telephone`, `ip`
```

When you have multiple rows per email with different values, you can still use aggregate functions. Not sum or count, but min and max work.

```
SELECT `email`, MIN(`firstname`) AS firstname , MIN(`lastname`) AS lastname, /* ... you get the idea */
FROM `order`
WHERE `customer_id` = 0 AND `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `ocustomer`)
GROUP BY `email`
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`.  It performs poorly, and does not work the way you need it to in this case.  Use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        o.`email`, o.`firstname`, o.`lastname`, o.`telephone`,
        o.`ip`, NULL
    FROM  `order` AS o
    LEFT JOIN  ocustomer AS oc USING(email)
    WHERE  o.`customer_id` = 0
      AND  oc.email IS NULL
```

Beneficial:

```
 order:     INDEX(customer_id)
 ocustomer: INDEX(email)
```

This may be even better, especially since it 'reads' like your statement of the problem:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        o.`email`, o.`firstname`, o.`lastname`, o.`telephone`,
        o.`ip`, NULL
    FROM  `order` AS o
    WHERE  o.`customer_id` = 0
      AND  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ocustomer WHERE email = o.email )
```

By using `DISTINCT` instead of the nearly-equivalent `GROUP BY`,

- It avoids the error message.
- It will show you if that email is associated with multiple names, phones, etc.

(Note:  Contrary to popular opinion, `SELECT DISTINCT(a), b ...` does not look just at `a` for "distinctifying".)